# TortoiseSVN Delete a branch in repo then recreate it

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We had a bit of an issue with Subversion (WANDisco) today.

We incorrectly created a branch a few days ago so we thought we would delete it then recreate it using TortoiseSVN.

We branched the root level folder (application1) which effectively duplicated our branches/tags/trunk.

So our repo structure is:

```
application1/trunk 
application1/branches
application1/tags
```

We wanted to branch the trunk, but we selected application1.  This created the following structure:

```
application1/branches/v5/trunk
application1/branches/v5/branches
application1/branches/v5/tags
```

We deleted application1/branches/v5 then branched application1/trunk to application1/branches/v5.

On our development PCs TortoiseSVN complained about conflicts with the folder when we did an Update of the application1/branches/V5 folder.  NOTE the developers already had this folder in their working copy.

We tried various combinations of the Clean Up to fix the issue.  It decided to restore the old V5 structure in some instances.

In the end we had to delete the entire working copy from development PCs then do a Checkout to finally get back to a working state.

Question is, how should you resolve this correctly?  Apart from be more careful when branching.

Answer (score 1):

Well as you quoted The First step must be...

**Be more careful while branching**

but if still you get into such issues, **you should provide your developers a alternate branch and ask them to switch before commiting anything**. This will keep their changes of working copy intact and then everything should go smooth.